# Is it possible to send a HEAD request from Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to run some validations on some urls (~less than 200 or so) but I don't want to run a typical GET request, only HEAD requests. Something along the lines of...

```
function main() {
  let params = {
    "method": "HEAD"
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("someUrl", params);
}
```

It's throwing an error stating the method value is invalid but I was wondering if anyone has worked around this? Can't seem to find any info on this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use `HEAD` requests with Apps Script. You can find the supported methods in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters):

> `method`: the HTTP method for the request: **get**, **delete**, **patch**, **post**, or **put**. The default is get.

You can also find this reported in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760627). A [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762291) was filed, but it's been a while so it may not be in their plans to add it.

##### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [HEAD method feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762291)